# Down arrow button for choosing the desired site

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

When searching for the desired SE site, the down arrow key (<kbd>down</kbd>) should work in order to choose the site one is looking for and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to visit it, instead of using the mouse point to choose it. Would be pretty convenient.

[image]

Comment: Worth to mention, this exact behavior already exists when choosing tags.

Comment: Using tab » down » Enter works fine and provide the same behaviour with one more keyboard action.

Comment: @FallenAngel: ah, hadn't tried that. Thanks, that's useful. I'd still rather just use the down arrow though.

Answer (score 5):

I've made a userscript for these purposes.

First, demo:

> [image]

Second, explanations, all apply only if the dropdown is expanded:

- First click on up/down arrows brings you to the list of all communities, further clicks navigate you up/down this menu.
- Typing something immediately sets focus to the search box.
- Clicking enter brings you to the selected community if any selected, otherwise scrolls you to the search box (latter is the default SE feature, unmodified)

Third, the script itself! [Download it from Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/10781-se-dropdown-kb-nav).