# Hide (or use) "More stack Exchange Communities" when editing your site-switcher list

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, top-bar, communities-list

Minor UI grumble: When you're editing your site switcher list the "More Stack Exchange communities" seems like unnecessary UI clutter.

[image: Das UI!]

Yes, I know one of them has a big "ADD" button next to it. Didn't stop me from using the wrong one.
I may be a blind idiot, but years of experience have taught me that's a good assumption about all users :)

---

I'd like to propose two possible changes to make it a little nicer:

**1 - Hide the "More Stack Exchange Communities" list when editing the switcher list.**
Quick and dirty fix with a little CSS & JS toggling `hidden`.

OR

**2 - *use* the "More Stack Exchange Communities" list for the editing**
Give `+` buttons in the More Stack Exchange Communities list, and `x` buttons in the Your Communities list when you hit edit. (You could even show the `+` button all the time - this would make adding communities to the switcher easier: Just Search & Click)

I like (2) myself even though it's probably more work to implement.

Comment: And while you're redesigning that thing, why do I have to click "Save"? Why isn't just the "Add" and "(x)" buttons enough?

Comment: @freiheit I'll give them the "Save" button as an implementation concession, otherwise it's a lot of server round-trips adding/removing/reordering options, and an indeterminate state (did my changes AJAX their way up to the server or not?)

Comment: Moving the "save" button up next to "cancel" would help. With a long list, the "Save" button is hidden. Even without a long list it's easy to miss since it's distant from the "edit" link that made it appear. With only a "cancel" button clearly visible it implies a full AJAXy auto-save functionality and an undo named "cancel".

Comment: Really, what I'm saying here is that the first time I used it, I totally missed the "Save" button. :)

Answer (score 4):

Starting with the next build we're going to fade out the other sections of the site switcher to make the editor more obvious:

[image]