# View only Stack Exchange sites which I have joined or am interested in in one window

Tags: support, user-accounts

My question is about how to remove the Stack Exchange sites I am not interested in.

A feature request or plugin to see all sites which I am interested in one portal window without a janky code work around: is there a plugin to do this?

I would like to see all of these below on one page =

- signal
- devops
- robotics and physics
- bioinfomatics
- software
- coffee
- Stack Overflow
- artifical inteligence
- programming
- arduino
- computer science
- data science
- electrical engineering
- iot
- information security

I wish I can see all of these in one window together. To not swap in and out of different communities to see various questions and answers, and see them all in the one window!

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't think this is about the HNQ.

Comment: Please don't edit your questions in an attempt to delete it.  Since there is now an answer, you can't delete it.  Those with over 10K reputation can vote to delete once it's closed, or you can flag it for a moderator to review to delete if you feel strongly about it.

Comment: Your edit has made your question dramatically worse.  Please put some more effort into properly editing it; I think your previous question was understandable.  This, not so much.

Comment: trying to remove as is duplicated in a later question, which is now a feature request instead

Comment: You can't remove it; only those with the correct privileges can.  Please stop making your question worse in an attempt to delete it.

Comment: Hi zip! I rolled back your question to a previous revision, that Glorfindel answered. Please don't edit this again in such a way that it invalidates that answer. If you want your other question to be a feature request, take some time to carefully edit and phrase that one into a proper feature request.

Comment: alrighty blueberry had the right one i think, i just fixed also

Answer (score 5):

You can find a list of accounts on your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts). You can also customize the YOUR COMMUNITIES list in the hamburger menu on the right; that won't hide the MORE STACK EXCHANGE COMMUNITIES list but you'd have to scroll down pretty far to get there.

Comment: i only see 5 available in the hamburger menu you mention? i would like to see all of these below on one page?

-signal
-bioinfomatics
-software
-coffee
-stackoverflow
-artifical inteligence
-programming
-arduino
-computer science
-data science
-electrical engineering
-iot
-information security

i wish i can see all of these in the one window together?

Comment: also -devops and - robotics and physics too

and remove all the rest and compile only interested ones in one window

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a manual on how to add communities there, but you could check https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224284/295232

Comment: @zip You only see five because that's the default. You can have more than that by clicking 'edit' in that menu. I have seven.

Comment: yes i added 15 in there now.. but still if a response happens in one category it does not get flagged in the inbox i have to go to each one to check, should there be a master inbox?