# Make it easier to add current site to "Your Communities"

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, top-bar, communities-list

Why isn't there an easy way to add the site one is currently on to the "Your communities" list? For example, when clicking the pulldown in the top left, there should be an "Add" button next to "Meta Stack Exchange", since that is the site I'm currently on. Or, on the homepage for a site, there should be an "Add to my communities" button. Maybe it's that I'm not detail attentive enough, but it took me forever to even notice the little "edit" button next to the pulldown in the upper left, and this is the only way to add a community to the "Your communities" list on the Desktop.

It is way easier to add communities to the list when on mobile.

Note, this is not a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224095/make-it-easier-to-edit-my-communities-list) because I am not requesting an easy way to add many communities at once, I am requesting a more obvious way to add the current community to the "Your communities" list.

Comment: Good suggestion, however whole new link  will be too much "noise" in the small area we have there. My idea is having the current site always on top of the list when clicking "edit", so that it's easy to add. :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes! I only have two use cases for "edit my communities"

- reorder them (I like to keep them in rep order)
- add the site I am on now to the list

I have **never** added a site to the list while on another site. But I have followed a hot question, realized I have a forgotten account on the site, and decided to add it to my communities so I won't forget again. And it's a reasonably laborious process to do so. The autocomplete even emphasises sites earlier in the alphabet over the site you're on! Just bring it to the top and life would get easier.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256693/make-it-easier-to-add-current-site-to-your-communities#comment837384_256693) that (and unfortunately) there isn't enough space in the drop down to add a link, especially as it'd need a fair bit of wording for it to make sense.

### Suggest

I suggest when we join a community "Are you sure you want to join..etc", have a tick box which states "Add this site to YOUR COMMUNITIES list".

While it's only a one time chance, it would be useful in itself.

### Other options

Maybe there's no *one* great place for this to be, so perhaps we need a few smaller options here and there.

So implement my idea above, as well as (again) [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256693/make-it-easier-to-add-current-site-to-your-communities#comment837384_256693)'s idea of:

> have the current site always on top of the list when clicking "edit",
>   so that it's easy to add

Although I would slightly alter that and suggest the "current" site being viewed is listed (once you've pressed edit link and have your list) *below* the search box and *above* the "Add" button. As putting it at the top of the list would make it seem like it's already on the list.

---

Or alternative to ShadowWizard's idea, is [KateGregory's idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256693/make-it-easier-to-add-current-site-to-your-communities/266796?noredirect=1#comment865562_266796):

> change the autocomplete area so that when you haven't typed anything
>   yet, it shows the current site.
>   Once you type a letter, if that
>   happens to be the first letter of the current site, continue to show
>   the current site first in the autocomplete list. As soon as your
>   typing deviates from the name of the current site, stop showing it in
>   the list.

Both ideas would work well.

---

### The better solution

Would be if the edit "YOUR COMMUNITIES" had another place to be managed, like in our profile somewhere. Given that there are many communities now, I think people could make better use of their list if it was easier to manage.

Perhaps leave it in the drop down as a "simple/quick add" option, and then we can go to our profile and manage it more in depth if required, with options such as:

- Sort view by
- Order list by
- Add one/bulk add
- Remove one/bulk remove
- Etc

This would cater for everyone's needs :)

Comment: you don't need room. Simply change the autocomplete area so that when you haven't typed anything yet, it shows the current site. Once you type a letter, if that happens to be the first letter of the current site, continue to show the current site first in the autocomplete list. As soon as your typing deviates from the name of the current site, stop showing it in the list. (The suggestion to add on join does nothing for my use case of "oh, I forgot I joined that site, I should add it to my list")

Comment: @KateGregory Nice idea. And I agree with your observed problem, as I said "While it's only a one time chance, it would be useful in itself" - useful for those who did not forget :)